# How to set ImageView permanently at a position after TranslateAnimation

Tags: java, android

I referenced the other questions but couldn't find a solution, also I am fairly new to programming.

So I implemented a TranslateAnimation on my ImageView but once the animation ends it returns to its original position. I used Override onAnimationEnd but that doesn't seem to work. Can someone figure out what should I be doing?

```
public class PackAnimation extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pack_animation);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("CHOICE");


    final ImageView pandya = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pandya);

    final int amountToMoveRight = 600;
    final int amountToMoveDown = 0;

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMoveRight, 0, amountToMoveDown);
    anim.setDuration(100);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)pandya.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin += amountToMoveDown;
            params.leftMargin += amountToMoveRight;
            pandya.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });

    pandya.startAnimation(anim);
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anim.setFillAfter(true)` to the `TranslateAnimation` and get the button stay at the new position, but the button clicks will not work at the new position.

So use `ViewPropertyAnimator` or `ObjectAnimator`. These are property animation and will change the position of the `View`, whereas the `TranslateAnimation` is View animation and will not change the actual property of the View.

For example, using `ViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
pandya.animate()
    .translationX(amountToMoveRight)
    .translationY(amountToMoveDown);
```

Refer the [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html) for more info:

> Finally, the previous animations changed the visual appearance of the
>   target objects... but they didn't actually change the objects
>   themselves. You may have run into this problem. Let's say you want to
>   move a Button from one side of the screen to the other. **You can use a
>   TranslateAnimation to do so, and the button will happily glide along
>   to the other side of the screen**. **And when the animation is done, it
>   will gladly snap back into its original location.** So you find the
>   setFillAfter(true) method on Animation and try it again. This time the
>   button stays in place at the location to which it was animated. And
>   you can verify that by clicking on it - Hey! How come the button isn't
>   clicking? The problem is that the animation changes where the button
>   is drawn, but not where the button physically exists within the
>   container. If you want to click on the button, you'll have to click
>   the location that it used to live in. Or, as a more effective solution
>   (and one just a tad more useful to your users), you'll have to write
>   your code to actually change the location of the button in the layout
>   when the animation finishes.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for mentioning the ViewPropertyAnimator, in the context that I'm working I think that's the best approach.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `anim.setFillAfter(true);` and it will remain on the final position after the end of animation.